# how should I study for the Euclid math contest?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

I am planning to take the Euclid math contest in April. The Euclid math contest is a contest issued by the university of waterloo for grade 12 students.

I am a grade 11 student who is very passionate about math. I self taught myself differential calculus in the summer and I thought it was really cool. I have no trouble with the stuff I am learning in math 12 right now yet when I looked at the Euclid math contest questions they are not AT ALL what we learned in the textbook.

I really need a good score on this contest to increase my admission chances. Any tips on where to start studying for it? Or how to start studying for it?

I went online and checked their eWorkshops but the stuff covered in there are basically just the things that we learned in the textbook and not at all like the questions on the contest. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The reason that these maths contests are difficult is because they do not always require a complex method or some high level maths you can’t learn at school, but instead you need to use initiative and take a different approach to what you would expect at first. Basically make sure that your fundamental understanding of methods is perfect then start working on these niche questions

Comment: ok cool, thanks for the heads up, so what should I do? Like do practice questions? From where? Any tips on what to study and how to study?

Comment: Any past questions you can get would definitely help. Try to do them all without looking at the method of others then see how your approach varies from a successful or faster approach

Comment: ok, but how would I do the practice questions if I don't even have a clue how to solve them in the first place? And by practice questions I assume you mean questions from previous euclid contests

Comment: Yep I mean previous papers. Try all the methods you know and get creative, if that doesn’t work then go through a walkthrough if you can find one

Comment: "they are not AT ALL what we learned in the textbook." That's a big problem with currently conventional textbooks and curricula. They try to give you a thorough mastery of ALL skills that might help you in courses that you may or may not take later, and they do little else. Anyone who doesn't see that that approach is thoroughly refuted has had his head buried deep in the sand for a half century or more.

Comment: If this is a test for 12 graders, then it needs to cover the material a 12 grader is supposed to know (and no more)  there will not be any calculus on the test.  As the questions advance it will require you to think increasingly creatively.  Other than reviewing past tests, I don't have many other suggestions.

Comment: ok, but how would questions help me if I don't even have a clue how to solve them? I can look through the answer keys but that won't really teach me anything. Plus the questions are limited. Only 10 questions per test, and I can only go back so many years

Comment: If you don't have a clue how to solve the questions, that should tell you something. You'll just have to rely on your other attributes & achievements to gain admission.